# How to decode base64 file into binary in Python?

Tags: python, io, binary, base64

I'm building a system which handles pdf file data (for which I use the [PyPDF2 lib](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2)). I now obtain a base64 encoded PDF which I can decode and store correctly using the following:

```
import base64
# base64FileData  <= the base64 file data
fileData = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(base64FileData.encode('UTF-8'))
with open('thefilename.pdf', 'w') as theFile:
    theFile.write(fileData)
```

I now want to use this `fileData` as a binary file to split it up, but when I do `type(fileData)`, the `fileData` turns out to be a `<type 'str'>`. How can I convert this `fileData` to be a binary (or at least not a string)?

All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]

if I do `open(fileData, 'rb')` I get an error, saying

> TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str

To remove the null bytes I tried, `fileData.rstrip(' \t\r\n\0')` and `fileData.rstrip('\0')` and `fileData.partition(b'\0')[0]`, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

[EDIT2]

The thing is that I pass this string to the [PyPDF2 PdfFileReader class](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/master/PyPDF2/pdf.py#L874-L916), which on [lines 909 to 912](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/master/PyPDF2/pdf.py#L874-L916) does the following (in which `stream` is the `fileData` I provide):

```
if type(stream) in (string_type, str):
    fileobj = open(stream, 'rb')
    stream = BytesIO(b_(fileobj.read()))
    fileobj.close()
```

So because its a string, it assumes it is a filename, after which it tries to open the file. This then fails with a `TypeError`. So before feeding the `fileData` to the PdfFileReader I need to somehow convert it to something else than `str` so that it doesn't try to open it, but just considers `fileData` a file on itself. Any ideas?

Comment: Concerning your edit: The first parameter of `open` has to be the filename not the content of your file. I guess you are using Python 2, `str` is just an alias for `bytes` in this version.

Comment: @halex - I added EDIT2 to my question. I'm starting to get more and more what the problem is. The main problem is that the test `if type(fileData) == str` succeeds, through which the system thinks its a filename instead of a a file. Any ideas how I could convert the `fileData` so that it passes the `if type(fileData) == str` test?

Answer (score 3):

Hence the open's [binary mode](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) you have to use 'wb' else it gets saved as "text" basically.

```
import base64
# base64FileData  <= the base64 file data
fileData = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(base64FileData.encode('UTF-8'))
with open('thefilename.pdf', 'wb') as theFile:
    theFile.write(fileData)
```

Comment: I guess my question was not clear; I need to have `fileData` (the variable) as binary, not `thefilename.pdf`. I added some more information to my question what I tried. Would you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Example your input data is came from this:

```
with open(local_image_path, "rb") as imageFile:
    str_image_data = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
```

then to get the binary in variable you can try:

```
import io
import base64

binary_image_data = io.BytesIO(base64.decodebytes(str_image_data))
```