# Converting binary representation to signed 64 bit integer in Python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

Against the advice of online resources, I'm using Python to do some simple bit shifting in one of my scripts. The bit shifting is fine, it's representing the result that's difficult. Let me explain.

I have a 64 bit binary representation

`1000010101010111010101010101010101010101010101010111010101010101`

which, when represented as a signed integer, should be negative. However, Python defaults to type `long`, preventing the number from being signed by the first bit, yielding the number `9608242155010487637`.

How can I get Python to recognize the sign bit in 64 bits?

To clarify, I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: You may find you answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305456/python-how-do-i-convert-from-binary-to-base-64-and-back http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016919/how-to-decode-base64-file-into-binary-in-python

Comment: @LoïcPoncin It's great that you are looking for dupe targets, but neither of those questions are particularly relevant to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`bitstring`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitstring/3.1.3) module:

```
>>> from bitstring import BitArray
>>> s = '1000010101010111010101010101010101010101010101010111010101010101'
>>> BitArray(bin=s).int
-8838501918699063979
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `struct`, like this:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('l',struct.pack('P',
int('1000010101010111010101010101010101010101010101010111010101010101',
2)))
#=> (-8838501918699063979,)
```

The result is a tuple, which you can then request the first element of:

```
>>> struct.unpack('l',struct.pack('P',
int('1000010101010111010101010101010101010101010101010111010101010101',
2)))[0]
#=> -8838501918699063979
```

Comment: I'm getting a struct error `struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4`

Comment: I changed the `l` argument to `q` in order to represent the 64 bit signed long, which fixed this error and gave me the correct result.