# 18-bit Signed Binary number to Decimal in Python

Tags: python

I have calculated the 2's complement of a binary number and represented it in the Binary format. Now, I am trying to convert the 18-bit Signed Binary Number to decimal numbers (-131072 to +131072).

When I use the int function it only gives unsigend values:-

```
number = 111111111111111110
print(int(str(number), 2))

Output = 262142
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting binary representation to signed 64 bit integer in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397772/converting-binary-representation-to-signed-64-bit-integer-in-python)

Comment: You could have written the number literal as `0b111111111111111110` and saved some time on conversions.

Comment: @jtbandes I have tried that, but it uses a built in library. Is it possible to do without it?

Comment: The code in your question parses a digit sequence as decimal, then unparses it as decimal, then parses the unparsed digit sequence as binary. If you just write `0b111111111111111110` as the other user suggests, you just parse the digit sequence once as binary.

Comment: This isn't "using a built-in library" any more than your original code, which already makes use of multiple forms of built-in digit sequence parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement the signed conversion manually by treating the high bit as negative:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...   return (x & ((1<<17) - 1)) - (x & (1<<17))
>>> foo(0b010000000000000000)
65536
>>> foo(0b100000000000000000)
-131072
>>> foo(0b111111111111111111)
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the string representation of a binary number, you can do this:

```
def todecimal(x, bits):
    assert len(x) <= bits
    n = int(x, 2)
    s = 1 << (bits - 1)
    return (n & s - 1) - (n & s)

print(todecimal('011111111111111111', 18))
print(todecimal('1', 18))
print(todecimal('100000000000000000', 18))
```

Note that the number of characters in the string must be less than or equal to the number of bits represented by the string.

**Output:**

```
131071
1
-131072
```